# Can the 'virtual' keyword be optimized away if no class re-implements it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, vtable

When I define a class in C++ I always define the dtor as virtual.
This is my way to protect myself in case I will write an inheriting class.

I wonder whether I pay the performance-overhead even in case I won't be inheriting the class.

For example:

```
class A final
{
    A();
    virtual ~A(){printf("dtor");}
};
```

When I use this class, will the dtor actually get called through a vtable or will it be implemented as a static dtor?

Comment: good question, but I personally would not recommend writing `virtual` by default here. Use it only if you also have other virtual functions in your class, otherwise it is not useful. Also -- you can answer this question by profiling your code. These kinds of tests are fun and interesting.

Comment: I think that the "cost" of forgetting the "virtual" keyword in a base class' dtor is much worse then the "cost" of calling each dtor in my code through a vtable.

Comment: I just saw you used `final` in which case you absolutely should not have marked the function as `virtual`. but even without `final` it is bad practice to add `virtual` if you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

> When I define a class in C++ I always define the dtor as virtual.

This is very bad practice. Classes should either be designed to be polymorphic... or not. It's not just an issue of design either - polymorphism adds overhead.

Now, good compilers when they see `delete a;` if they can prove that `a` will only ever be of type `A`, will remove the virtual call and directly call `~A()`. This is called devirtualization. But what they won't do is remove the vtable. Adding unnecessarily polymorphism means all your types now have vtables which means they're all using extra space. In your simple example, the presence of `virtual` increases `sizeof(A)` from 1 to 8. If you have a lot of `A`s, you're now messing with cache effects. This is bad.

In short, design your classes according to their use. Not according to some problems that you may or may not eventually have if they are misused.

> This is my way to protect myself in case I will write an inheriting class.

Note also that not all inheritance must be polymorphic - not even classes that intend to be inherited from from need to have a `virtual` destructor. That's only necessary if the usage is to hold onto a `Base*` and then `delete` it. It's perfectly safe for me to inherit from something like `std::vector<>` to provide a different interface - as long as I'm not trying to `delete` my inherited type through `std::vector<>`.

---

On the other hand, this

```
class A final { ... };
```

is good practice! If `A` isn't intended to be inherited from so explicitly make it ill-formed to inherit from it. Now, when you need to inherit from `A`, you have to make a conscious effort to think about the consequences of doing so.

Comment: But generally classes are created/exists for the very purpose of getting extended. Otherwise POD `struct` can be used.

Comment: @sameerkn Citation needed.

Comment: @sameerkn: In C++, `struct` defines a _class_. I'm not kidding, that is the actual language specification. `struct` only affects the default access of members, until the first explicit access specifier.

Comment: `final` keyword makes sense if the only intention is to use a `class` as some compact entity storing data and functions which provide access to those data.

Comment: @sameerkn The `final` keyword on the class level is orthogonal to `virtual` functions and the `final` keyword thereon. A class can be non-`final` for the purpose of allowing future addition of members and methods, without ever having to contain a `virtual` destructor or any other virtual methods. Declaring the destructor as `virtual`, if the class can (in terms of Murphy, not Machiavelli) never be deleted through a pointer to one of its base classes, is always paying for what you don't use. Pointless making it `virtual` when it can never be overridden is even more so, to a paradoxical degree.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you declared the class as final, it cannot be used as base class for any other one. So the virtual does not make sense.

Because of the *as if* rule, the compiler is then free to ignore the *virtual* keyboard, but it is not required to do it. BTW the mere existence of a vtable is an implementation detail and is not required by the standard.

TL/DR: it depends on the compiler implementation.

Comment: Technically speaking, the compiler may use vtables for non-polymorphic classes as well. The main problem with that is finding a place for the vptr.